# Parsing a string with different separators

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am creating a parser that has mostly similar lines of data but not entirely the same.

This is javascript code I am writing for those asking.

For instance this line:

> [16/Nov/2022:12:00:36.523 -0800] BIND RESULT threadID=8 conn=641870 op=11958 msgID=11959 version="3" dn="cn=Directory Manager" authType="SIMPLE" resultCode=0 resultCodeName="Success" qtime=0 etime=0.185 authDN="cn=LDAP Root,cn=Root DNs,cn=config" clientConnectionPolicy="default"

I originally thought spliting the string based on the " " as a separater worked up until I go to the `authDN=...` section of the string.  It is separating the LDAP from Root and creating 2 entries.

Does anyone know how I can create a parser method to successfully separate these key=value pairs when some of the have ' ' in the value section.

Thank you for anyone help.

My code:

```
data=str.split(" ");
for (x in data){
switch (x){
case 0:
TimeStamp=data\[x\] + " " + data\[x+1\];
break;
case 1:
break;
case 2:
entryType=data\[x\] + " " + data\[x+1\];
break;
case 3:
break;
default:
entry.setAttribute(data\[x\].toString().split('=')\[0\],data\[x\].toString().split('=')\[1\]);

break;
}
}
```

When I get to `authDN="cn=Directory Manager,cn=Root DNs,cn=config"`  I am getting `'authDN="cn=Directory'` and then `'Manager,cn=Root'` and finally `'DNs'`

Comment: Your code was a complete wreck, and while I've fixed it a little, it urgently needs proper indentation. It's also severely mangled somehow with backslashes. All you need to do is indent four spaces and it will be presented properly, not whatever you did to this code.

Comment: Why `split` and not some regexp? Writing one that teases out `x=y` and `x="..."` forms should be straightforward. Do you want it to return whatever it can parse safely, ignoring the rest, or fail if it can't parse properly?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```js
function parseBindResult(line) {
  var isInQuote = false;
  var quote = "";
  var quoteKey = ""
  var result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    if (isInQuote) {
      if (line[i] == '"') {
        isInQuote = false
        result[quoteKey] = quote.replace('"', '')
        quote = "";
        continue;
      }
      quote += line[i];
      continue;
    }
    // if the letter is an "=", everything from a \s to the "=" is the key, and everything from the "=" to the next \s is the value.
    if (line[i] === "=") {
      // the key is everything from the last \s to the "="
      var key = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" ", i) !== -1 ? line.lastIndexOf(" ", i) : 0, i).trim()
      // the value is everything from the "=" to the next \s
      var value = line.substring(i + 1, line.indexOf(" ", i) !== -1 ? line.indexOf(" ", i) : line.length).trim();
      // if the value is in quotes, it's a nested object
      if (line[i + 1] === '"') {
        i++;
        isInQuote = true;
        quoteKey = key;
        continue;
      }
      result[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

```js
{
  threadID: '8',
  conn: '641870',
  op: '11958',
  msgID: '11959',
  version: '3',
  dn: 'cn=Directory Manager',
  authType: 'SIMPLE',
  resultCode: '0',
  resultCodeName: 'Success',
  qtime: '0',
  etime: '0.185',
  authDN: 'cn=LDAP Root,cn=Root DNs,cn=config',
  clientConnectionPolicy: 'default'
}
```

If you want to use sub-objects, then this code will work:

```js
function parseBindResult(line, seperator = " ") {
  var isInQuote = false;
  var quote = "";
  var quoteKey = ""
  var result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    if (isInQuote) {
      if (line[i] == '"') {
        isInQuote = false
        result[quoteKey] = parseBindResult(quote.replace('"', ''), ",");
        quote = "";
        continue;
      }
      quote += line[i];
      continue;
    }
    // if the letter is an "=", everything from a \s to the "=" is the key, and everything from the "=" to the next \s is the value.
    if (line[i] === "=") {
      // the key is everything from the last \s to the "="
      var key = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(seperator, i) !== -1 ? line.lastIndexOf(seperator, i) : 0, i).replace(new RegExp(`${seperator}*$`), '').replace(new RegExp(`^${seperator}*`), '')
      // the value is everything from the "=" to the next \s
      var value = line.substring(i + 1, line.indexOf(seperator, i) !== -1 ? line.indexOf(seperator, i) : line.length).replace(new RegExp(`${seperator}*$`), '').replace(new RegExp(`^${seperator}*`), '')
      // if the value is in quotes, it's a nested object
      if (line[i + 1] === '"') {
        i++;
        isInQuote = true;
        quoteKey = key;
        continue;
      }
      result[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

```js
{
  threadID: '8',
  conn: '641870',
  op: '11958',
  msgID: '11959',
  version: {},
  dn: { cn: 'Directory Manager' },
  authType: {},
  resultCode: '0',
  resultCodeName: {},
  qtime: '0',
  etime: '0.185',
  authDN: { cn: 'config' }, // It will overwrite anything with multiple instances of the same key
  clientConnectionPolicy: {}
}
```